# Does programming to an interface include extended classes

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have following class

```
public class RegisterUserDetails extends DatabaseCall {
public String setAddUserQuery(User user){
  //code

  return query;
 }
}
```

And here is the DatabaseCall class

```
public class DatabaseCall {
public ResultSet executeQuery(String query){
//code
return rs;
}

}
```

I was trying to program to a supertype/interface by doing this

```
DatabaseCall dbCall = new RegisterUserDetails();
```

However I cannot view the setAddUserQuery method this way. Why is this?
It seems programming to an interface is only applicable for abstract classes and interfaces?

Comment: It's the slicing problem: The DatabaseCall API does not include a method called setAddUserQuery.  Only RegisterUserDetails has that method.  You can either move that method into the super class OR cast the reference.

Comment: Programming to an interface will fail with abstract classes and interfaces if you add public methods that are not part of the parent's contract and make them required for use. This has nothing to do with what the parent of the child happens to be.

Comment: *"Why is this?"* - Because `DatabaseCall` doesn't provide any methods called `setAddUserQuery` - this is polymorphism in action, the `RegisterUserDetails` is capable of been used as `DatabaseCall` as it extends `DatabaseCall`, but in doing so, it can only perform the operations that `DatabaseCall` defines

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [*What does it mean to “program to an interface”?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface) Do the answers there answer this question?

Comment: Hint: it is not exactly good practice to put up such an unclear question. And to then just walk away, and leave the people who try to help you without any feedback ... doesn't improve the situation. I am *really* surprised that I am the first one to close-request this.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was "such an unclear" question, i went into details and gave example code and as a result I got the answer I wanted. I do appreciate it was a long time, but things happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However I cannot view the setAddUserQuery method this way. Why is this?

Because `DatabaseCall` doesn't have `setAdduserQuery`. The interface you have to the object doesn't have the method.

> It seems programming to an interface is only applicable for abstract classes and interfaces?

No, it's not at all limited to that. But the interface you have (defined by interface or class) must have the features you need. In your case, `DatabaseCall` doesn't have the feature (`setAddUserQuery`) that you need.

It may be that you should add it to `DatabaseCall`, or that the specific code that needs to use `setAddUserQuery` needs to be written to a more feature-rich interface (one that includes `setAddUserQuery`; perhaps `RegisterUserDetails`).

But the goal of programming to an interface is to program to the features required, rather than a concrete type. The interface (features required) still has to have all of the features you need. For instance, you program to `List` rather than `ArrayList`, because `List` has all the features you need, so there's no need to work with the concrete type, and later you may find it's useful to use `LinkedList` instead.